# Why thread code is taking more time than sequential code in c++?

Tags: c++, c++11

i went to multiply matrix[1000][1000] by vector[1000] using sequetial code and thread code and the calc the time performance ?

//use this command to run the program:-
//g++ -fopenmp -std=c++11 -O3 -o OMPmonti OMPmonti.cpp -lpthread

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

#define SIZE 1000

int main()
{
std::clock_t    start;
    start = std::clock();

    int MATRIX[SIZE][SIZE]={0};
    int VECTOR[SIZE]={0};
    int RESULT[SIZE]={0};

    for(int i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
    {
        int x=i;
        for(int j=0;j<SIZE;j++)
        {
            MATRIX[i][j]=x;
            x=x+1;
        }
        VECTOR[i]=i;

    }

    for(int i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<SIZE;j++)
            RESULT[i]+=MATRIX[i][j]*VECTOR[j];

    ofstream output("result.txt");
        for(int i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
            output<<RESULT[i]<<"\n";
    output.close();

    std::cout << "Time: " << (std::clock() - start) / (double)(CLOCKS_PER_SEC / 1000) << " ms" << std::endl;

    return 0;


}
```

the thread code is :-

```
//use this command to run the program:-
//g++ -fopenmp -std=c++11 -O3 -o OMPmonti OMPmonti.cpp -lpthread

#include<iostream>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<fstream>
#include <ctime>


using namespace std;

#define SIZE 1000

int NUM_THREADS;


int MATRIX[SIZE][SIZE]={0};
int VECTOR[SIZE]={0};
int RESULT[SIZE]={0};

struct BOUNDARIES{
    int START;
    int END;
};

void *MUL_ROUTINE(void *PARAM)
{
    BOUNDARIES *info= ( BOUNDARIES *) PARAM;
    for(int i=info->START;i<=info->END;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<SIZE;j++)
            RESULT[i]+=MATRIX[i][j]*VECTOR[j];

pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main()
{
    std::clock_t    start;
    start = std::clock();

    for(int i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
    {
        int x=i;
        for(int j=0;j<SIZE;j++)
        {
            MATRIX[i][j]=x;
            x=x+1;
        }
        VECTOR[i]=i;

    }


    NUM_THREADS=4;

    pthread_t THREADS[NUM_THREADS];
    BOUNDARIES info[NUM_THREADS];

    int ret;

    for(int i=0;i<NUM_THREADS;i++)
    {
        if(i==0)
            info[i].START=0;
        else
            info[i].START=info[i-1].END+1;

        info[i].END=info[i].START+(SIZE/NUM_THREADS-1);
        if(i<(SIZE%NUM_THREADS))
            info[i].END++;

        ret=pthread_create(&THREADS[i],NULL,&MUL_ROUTINE,&info[i]);
        if(ret)
        {
            cout<<"Error Creating Thread "<<i<<endl;
            cout<<"Terminating The Program......"<<endl;
            return 0;
        }
    }

    for(int i=0;i<NUM_THREADS;i++)
        pthread_join(THREADS[i],0);

    ofstream output("result1.txt");
    for(int i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
        output<<RESULT[i]<<"\n";
    output.close();

    std::cout << "Time: " << (std::clock() - start) / (double)(CLOCKS_PER_SEC / 1000) << " ms" << std::endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And what is the problem that you encountered with your code ? (not very clear what you are asking...)

Comment: My guess is, that for this task, overhead of creating threads is bigger, than the gain from the calculation. Since it doesn't even need 0.5 sec to complete the sequential code (with debug build, without any optimizations). I couldn't really test the parallel case, since I don't have pthread on my system, and needed to do tweaks to your code to even run sequential code (that 4MB stack requirement, though!).

Comment: Want to share your results?

Comment: My problem is that sequential code its take about 2.5 ms and the thread is taking about 2.8 ms.

Comment: I am asking if there is something wrong with my code to have bad performance !!!!

Comment: What happens if you try just two threads? Is there a way to force each thread to run on a separate core? If the time it takes to do an integer multiply is as fast or nearly as fast as accessing data, which could be in local (to each core) cache, common (to all cores) cache, or main memory, multiple threads won't help.

Comment: I dont know if there is away to firce each thread in a core but.i try to use tow thread and getvthe same performance.!

Answer (score 0):

You are also measuring the time of the thread creation. Lets assume it takes 1.9ms to create those 4 threads. After that each thread performs it's calculation and after 0,625ms every thread is done.

To conclude the above example: Those time-measurements are unfair! You should not compare two pieces of code that do not do the same!

You can try to put your start clock after the loop that creates the threads. But you may realize that this is also unfair because the first threads may have already been started. So in either case you wont get the time it took to perform the calculation.

Well to see a benefit you should use a more expensive calculation that takes several seconds in the single core case. After that the 2ms that it takes to create those threads are insignificant.

Answer (score 0):

From the man page of `clock(3)`:

> DESCRIPTION
>   The clock() function returns an approximation of **processor** time used by the
>          program.

You are measuring the CPU time that the execution of your two programs takes. Since there is always overhead related to communication and synchronization in threaded programming, the CPU time will never be lower than that of a sequential program.

But that mostly doesn't matter because the **real** time is lower - you're just not measuring it. To do that you could

1. `#include <omp.h>` and use the `double omp_get_wtime()` function
2. use the function `clock_gettime` with `CLOCK_REALTIME` from `<ctime>`
3. use any of the clocks available in `#include <chrono>`

You have to know what you're measuring to be able to draw conclusions.